# Couldn't match expected type ‘Char’ with actual type ‘[Char]’

Tags: haskell

```
censor :: [Char] -> [Char]
censor [] = []
censor (x:xs)
    |x `elem` "aeiou" = "X" : censor xs
    |otherwise = x : censor xs
```

my code is supposed to censor lower-case vowels and replace them with an x however i am getting the error in my title, any suggestions? Thanks.

Edit: had to put spaces on here for formatting take them away while looking

Comment: censor :: [Char] -> [Char]
censor [] = []
censor (x:xs)
   |x `elem` "aeiou" = "X" : censor xs
   |otherwise = x : censor xs

Comment: There is currently 3 downvotes with no comments whatsoever. Why?!

Comment: Why are we artificially increasing the already-high barrier to entry to Haskell?

Comment: The error message (in GHC 7.10) points to `x : censor xs`, not `"X" : censor xs` as the location of the error, which is probably the cause of the confusion.

Answer (score 7):

You are trying to prepend the string `"X"` instead of the character `'X'`:

```
| x `elem` "aeiou" = 'X' : censor xs
```

The rest of your code is fine.